# How to check whether an Object is Present in the scene or not in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add and remove objects to my scene in clicks.

Simply I use `scene.add(object)` and `scene.remove(object)`.

Is there any way to check whether the object is present in the scene?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When adding your object to scene, add name to that object like

```
object.name = 'object_name';
```

Then you can check if your object exist in scene by

```
scene.getObjectByName('object_name');
```

If it return any object it means object exist in scene.

Answer (score 5):

Probably more efficient:
`object.parent === scene`

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why they think this is not a good solution?

Comment: because objects can have the scene as their grandparent, as well. So this solution doesn't always work.

Comment: Yes but the OP said they only added objects directly to the scene...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this:

```js
    function isObjectInScene(scene, object) {
    
        let current_object = object;

        while(current_object.parent !== null) {
            current_object = current_object.parent;
    
            if(current_object === scene) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        return false;
            
    }
```

@Neptilo [was on the right track I believe.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894518/5654507)
If the object is in the scene, either the object's parent, or it's parent's parent, or it's parent's parent's parent (and so) should be the scene itself.

So an object is within a scene, and if you keep following the parent references upwards, eventually you should encounter the scene, and if you don't, then the object is not within that scene.

When objects are removed with scene/obj.remove(obj), they have their parent value set to null, and initialise as null as well.

I suspect any other means of checking if an object is in a scene, such as checking for objects by name or ID, will involve some kind of transversal of the entire scene, which would be slower than just checking the parent chain until you find the root.